# How to forbid a locked out user to login in .NET Core 6 Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a custom user store in my .NET Core 6 site. The corresponding user table in DB contains a field called `Lockout`.

When a user signs in, I need that field to be used to forbid the user to login if that field is true.

The `Login` action of the Account Controller has this code:

```
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Login, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var appUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Login);
                if (appUser.Roles == null || appUser.Roles.Count == 0)
                {
                    await PerformLogOff();
                    return Json("ERROR: No tiene autorización para ingresar al sistema.");
                }
                else
                {
                    returnUrl ??= Request.Path.ToString();
                    appUser.LastLoggedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    if (!appUser.FirstLoggedOn.HasValue)
                        appUser.FirstLoggedOn = appUser.LastLoggedOn;
                    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(appUser);
                    return Json(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            else if (result.IsLockedOut)
                return Json("ERROR: Su usuario está bloqueado.");
            else if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                return Json("ERROR: El usuario requiere autenticación de doble factor.");
            else
                return Json("ERROR: Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");
```

When a user is locked out, I need `PasswordSignInAsync` to return `result.IsLockedOut`.

How can I do it? Should I create a custom `SignInManager`? Notice that this has nothing to do with locking a user out when he fails to enter the password several times in login screen.

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 3):

You can do it your self by adding another filed (e.g. IsActive) to the your ApplicationUser class. Then you can check it before the line "_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync" with some code like this:

```
var user = await _userManager.Users.Where(s => s.UserName == model.Username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!user.IsActive)
                {
    
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User has been deactivated");
//Log the failure
                   
                    return View();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read source code about [`SignInManager.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L346-L354). And it should support forbid lockout user.

For more details, check the blog below, it contains the code useful to you.

[User Lockout with ASP.NET Core Identity](https://code-maze.com/user-lockout-aspnet-core-identity/)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IactionResult> Login(UserLoginModel userModel, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(userModel);
    }

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userModel.Email, userModel.Password, userModel.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        var forgotPassLink = Url.Action(nameof(ForgotPassword),"Account", new { }, Request.Scheme);
        var content = string.Format("Your account is locked out, to reset your password, please click this link: {0}", forgotPassLink);

        var message = new Message(new string[] { userModel.Email }, "Locked out account information", content, null);
        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(message);

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The account is locked out");
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Attempt");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. That Lockout feature is when a user fails to enter his password certain number of times.. In my case, I don't need such a feature. I lock users out on demand so I need the sign in manager to check the Lockout field of my custom application user. An alternative I have is to get the application user in the `Login` action after the call to `PasswordSignInAsync`. If `Lockout` property is true, then, the user should be logged out and sends the corresponding message to the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want `result.IsLockedOut` to be `true` then I can see two options:

1. You would need to extend `UserManager` or `AspNetUserManager` and override virtual method `IsLockedOutAsync` ([code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/11eeb8c34c6f84b5098fb5cfc069e3fc0e1efac5/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1913)) so it will be returning `false` based on your `Lockout` property.
2. I don't know internals of your store but you could also manually set original `LockoutEnd` field in database to date from the next century e.g.:`3000-01-01` when your application logic wants to set it to `true` or clear the field to unlock the user

For both options you need to watch out - `SignInManager` will only attempt to check lockouts if feature is enabled ([code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L346)).

To enable it you should make sure that your custom `UserStore` implements `IUserLockoutStore<TUser>` interface. Simple override of `SupportsUserLockout` ([code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/11eeb8c34c6f84b5098fb5cfc069e3fc0e1efac5/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L348)) virtual property to return always `true` in your custom `UserManager` might not work - because there are few other operations made on `UserStore` to count failures etc.

Probably you are not looking for opinion but I feel that your idea from comment to load user in `Login` action and check your custom property is the cleanest. It is not only about hacking your solution here - but it is usualy very harmful in development teams to change well documented, battle-tested frameworks like `Identity` to behave in a different way.